# JUnit test case failure with JMockit java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid context for the recording of expectations

Tags: java, junit, jmockit, expectations

```
@Test
public void testGetOnlyNewPartitions() throws Exception {
    setUp();
    new Expectations(){
        HiveUtil hiveUtil;
        {
            HiveUtil.getInstance(); returns(hiveUtil);
            hiveUtil.getAllpartitions(oldTable); returns(oldPartitions);
            hiveUtil.getAllpartitions(newTable); returns(newPartitions);
        }
    };
    PartitionFilter partitionFilter = new PartitionFilter(oldTable, newTable, HiveUtil.getInstance());
}
```

I am unit testing the class PartitionFilter, which uses a singleton class HiveUtil.

My test case is failing with the error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid context for the recording of expectations" while running. Any explanation on why this is happening?

This is the relevant part of my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
         <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
         <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
         <version>1.13</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
</dependency>
```

I have tried to put the jmockit dependency before the junit dependency in the pom. That didn't work.

Some more research suggested that I was not using the @RunWith(JMockit.class) annotation at the beginning of the class.
However, when I tried to use it, I was presented with the error "Class cannot be resolved to a type". I made all the relevant imports.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.*;

import mockit.*;
import mockit.integration.junit4.*;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is this import trying to do? import static mockit.Mockit.*; I don't see a Mockit class in the mockit package of the JMockIt API

Comment: My bad. That was a suggestion I was trying. Removed that.

Comment: which line gives you the class cannot be resolved to a type? are you seeing the dependencies under maven library in eclipse?

Comment: also the way you have written the test case is a little odd. What's the returns for? They keyword result is used to mark a return value,

new NonStrictExpectations() {
      {
        d.toString();
        result = "mocked date";
      }
    };

Comment: I used the returns after reading its use from this link : http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r224/trunk/www/tutorial/AnExample.html

And the class cannot be resolved to a type is received in the line @RunWith(JMockit.class)

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of JMockit (since version 1.7) require the use of a mocking annotation to introduce a mocked type/instance. Also, *local* mock fields are no longer supported. So, the test should be written as follows:

```
@Test
public void getOnlyNewPartitions(@Mocked final HiveUtil hiveUtil) throws Exception {
    setUp();

    new Expectations() {{
        hiveUtil.getAllpartitions(oldTable); result = oldPartitions;
        hiveUtil.getAllpartitions(newTable); result = newPartitions;
    }};

    PartitionFilter partitionFilter = 
        new PartitionFilter(oldTable, newTable, HiveUtil.getInstance());
}
```

Comment: This works. But I get the following message in my console :
"WARNING: JMockit was initialized on demand, which may cause certain tests to fail;
please check the documentation for better ways to get it initialized."